# How can I uninstall and reinstall ubuntu from a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, windows-xp

I have attempted to remove Ubuntu from a dual boot system (Windows XP, SP3) by deleting partitions, using both the Ubuntu install CD and GParted. Neither worked for me; instead, all I did was manage to install a new version of Ubuntu each time. Now, I have 3 versions of Ubuntu and one of XP. Trouble is, I cannot boot up XP. Each time I select it from the boot list, a message appears briefly saying chkdsk needs to be run, but instead of running chkdks, my computer restarts. I can boot up Ubuntu, so I have a way of getting online, if that is needed to find a solution.

Comment: Did you try running chkdisk form live-cd?

Comment: Ask for chkdks normally means something wrong with your Windows partition. Try that first from Live cd or Windows XP install CD. It have nothing to do with uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu, but I personally think it is more important and easier.

Comment: It sounds like all the versions of Ubuntu are on your MBR, but not on your hard disk (except the one you can boot up from.) Can you boot into all 3 versions? Are you sure you have deleted the partitions? Could you please post the output of "fdisk -l" while you are in Ubuntu, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 3):

## This will erase all data on your computer

1. Boot to a live CD. You'll know you are on the live CD because it will have an icon called 'Install Ubuntu' on the desktop and your username (`whoami` in terminal) is 'ubuntu'
2. Open GParted (looks like this: [screenshot](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screens/gparted_1_big.png))
3. Right click on each line and select the 'Partition' Menu, then 'Delete' ([screenshot](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screens/gparted_7_big.png))
4. Repeat until there is only one line left that reads 'Unallocated Space'
5. Click the Commit button (Green Checkmark), if you pressed the right one then [this](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screens/gparted_2_big.png) will appear
6. Once it is done, expand the details and make sure every action has a green checkmark, like [this](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screens/gparted_9_big.png)

If for some reason you follow each of the directions above and your computer still boots into ubuntu or windows then you likely have more than one hard drive.

### Alternative method (faster)

1. Follow 1 & 2 from above.
2. Click the 'Device' menu, then 'Create Partition Table' ([screenshot](http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/create-new-partition-table-hparted.jpg))

Comment: You can keep Windows XP by simply skipping any partition formatted as `fat32` or `ntfs` but still following all the other directions (all steps except #4). You cannot use the alternate method if you want to keep XP.